# How to return an excel type generated by jasper with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this metod that returns a pdf in a array of bytes and I would like to generate an excel type. How can I do this?
In "headers.setContentType" doesn't have a csv or xls type that I can use.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> imprimir(List<Notificacao> notificacoes) throws Exception {

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getPathToReportPackage() + "notificacoes.jrxml");

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(notificacoes));

    byte[] bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    String filename = "notificacao.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    return response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Excel**:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
```

**CSV**:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"));
```

You can find a complete list of Mime Types on this link.

https://slick.pl/kb/htaccess/complete-list-mime-types/